# How can I access my desktop from my laptop on my private home network?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan

I want to set up my first home network and have read up on LAN configuration, but am choking now that I'm actually trying to venture out on my own without the help of a tutorial.

My equipment:

- NetGear wireless router
- PC that I will use as my "server" running Ubuntu
- Plenty of Cat5 cable (if need be for any reason)
- Laptop - a "client" that will connect to the server for certain uses

I have already set up a secure wireless network on my router. This will also be an "intranet" and the router does not have access to the open internet (which is intentional). So unless I'm missing something, the secure password on the network should be the only security I really need (again this is just a test LAN that I'll use for miscellaneous, non-critical purposes).

I have installed Subversion (SVN) on the Ubuntu "server" and would like to connect to use it to commit/checkout code from my laptop.

I can see my wireless network from my laptop but am choking on how to connect the SVN client on my laptop to the SVN server on my desktop "server". Thanks to anyone who can nudge me in the right direction!

Comment: Have you tried accessing it by name, or perhaps IP address?  Can you ping the server from the notebook?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Does the router automatically assign my server an IP address? If not, what do I need to do to give the server one?

Comment: If you have the router (or something) setup to give out DHCP then yes it should get one, otherwise you'll have to hard-set them.  We can't see your network, you'd have to tell us how you set it up. :)

Comment: Thanks @techie007 - yes I can see my server's IP address. A quick assertion I'd like to make, and if its wrong please correct me! I assume that when you install a server and launch it, it looks to a particular port # for incoming messages. Clients can then communicate with the servers by sending messages to the correct port, yes? If so, then my SVN client and server - while running - should be trying to communicate with each other over the same port. But how do I tell my client which IP address the server is on in the first place?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have setup your svn server and added a repository you should be able to check it form the client machine via terminal using the following command

```
svn co svn://192.168.0.2/svnrepos/myyrailsproject
```

replacing your IP and repositroy directory.

Comment: @AdamTannon  Usually, Thanking happens by +1 ing.